# finding the difference between two different data frame by using pd

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Columns1":[A, B, C, D]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Columns1":[A, B, C]})
```

As you seen the difference between two data frame is D becouse it is in df and there is not in df2

how can i use pandas or other to find the difference and replace it in new data frame ?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Desire output is to tell you D is not in the dataframe df2